# ArrayResize() creates undefined objects

Tags: arrays, coldfusion, coldfusion-11

I want an array of 16 blank items

I don't want to

```
this.arConfig = ['','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','',''];
```

When I try

```
ArrayResize(this.arConfig, 16);
```

I get

[image]

Is there a way to cleanly load this. Note: I expect that someday 16 won't be enough.

Comment: For very small arrays, an alternative to hard coding is: `listToArray(repeatString("'',",16));`

Comment: What are you perceiving is actually *wrong* with what you're seeing there? You don't say. What was it you were expecting to see? Is it that you want to be able to access the array elements without a "Element n is undefined in a Java object of type class coldfusion.runtime.Array" exception, if you access element n before giving it a value?

Comment: I was hoping for blank strings

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just don't use `ArrayResize()` for such a small array. It is meant for LARGE arrays. Anyway, that's how it works, what do you expect? Anyway, there's `ArraySet()` if you really need it.

https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/ArraySet